# Interesting parent and child behavior while doing fork

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

Can someone please explain the output of the program below . Why am i getting the same value of &a for both parent and child.

They must have the different physical address.If i consider that i am getting the virtual address then how can they have same virtual address because as far as i know each physical address is uniquely bound to virtual address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {


    int pid=fork();
      int a=10;
    if(pid==0)
        {
            a=a+5;
            printf("%d %d\n",a,&a);
        }
        else
        {
            a=a-5;
            printf("%d %d\n",a,&a);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The child process inherits its virtual address space from the parent, even though the virtual addresses start referring to different physical addresses once the child writes to a page. That's called copy-on-write (CoW) semantics.

So, in the parent `&a` is mapped to some physical address. Fork initially just copies the mapping. Then, when the processes write to `a`, CoW kicks in and in the child process, the physical page that holds `a` is copied, the virtual address mapping is updated to refer to the copy and both processes have their own copy of `a`, at the same virtual address `&a` but at different physical addresses.

> each physical address is uniquely bound to virtual address

That's not true. A physical memory address may be unmapped, or it may be mapped to multiple virtual addresses in one or more processes' address spaces.

Conversely, a single virtual address can be mapped to several physical address, as long as these virtual addresses exist in different processes' virtual address spaces.

[Btw., you can't reliably print memory addresses with `%d` (that just happens to work on 32-bit x86). Use `%p` instead. Also, the return type of `fork` is `pid_t`, not `int`.]

Comment: This is a good answer but I think you should make clearer that the virtual:physical mapping is M:N -- not only can the same physical address be mapped to multiple virtual addresses (in one or more address spaces), the same *virtual* address can be mapped to multiple *physical* addresses (but of course no more than one such mapping per address space).  The latter seems to be the point of confusion here.